# viewcontroller is not switching to landscape mode after putting it in the front screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, core-graphics

This is my first ios project which is ipad specific. In this project I have two view controllers in which I have made my custom drawing using the `drawRect` method.

Each view of the `UIViewController` has several circles drawn on them. The app can run only in landscape mode.  Now I have made another view controller which has two `UITextField`'s based on username and password & made this view controller to display in the front when the app launches. Here is where the problem arises. The two `UITextField`'s were placed in the XIB file in portrait mode. But I want them to be placed in landscape mode, as the other two view controllers are in landscape mode.
                                                                                           My question is

1. Is it possible to create  `UITextField` in the interface builder in landscape mode? I have tried with auto-rotation but it was not successful.
2. If I have to match a certain text value in the username and password field, and switch to another view controller, do I need to use custom delegate

EDIT: here is the screen shoot of my interface builder![screen shoot of my XIB file][1]

![1]: (http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/4733/screenshot20130528at622.png)

Comment: Use autosizing properties in the Interface builder. This will ensure the position of your subviews (`UITextFields`) is relative to the height and width of the superview (`UIViewController's` view).

Comment: you set x and y  position of textfield  when it landscape mode

Comment: Is autosizing property in the interface builder? could you please tell me how can i find it?

Comment: what happens when you change the orientation in simulation metrics, after clicking on your viewcontroller?

Comment: @MarkRamotowski I have uploaded my screen shoot.please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: orientation change]

Try changing the orientation property in storyboard

Comment: And to answer question 2 (although I think they should be completely separate questions on stack overflow), no you do not need a delegate for that. That code should come in your view controller subclass

Comment: I have uploaded my screen shoot.please have a look

Comment: change portrait to landscape?